# How do I increase Crota's Bane with The Taken King?

Tags: destiny

Through the release of *The Taken King*, Eris Morn not only moved locations, all of her bounties are no longer available.

How does one go about gaining *Crota's Bane* reputation without her bounties?

There was one mission that rewarded some reputation, but other than that,  I have not found any other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crota's Bane reputation can be earned in five main ways in The Taken King.

- Completing encounters in Crota's End and King's Fall grants reputation.
- While Eris herself does not offer bounties, she still plays a part in several quest chains that grant reputation.
- Opening the event treasure chests on The Dreadnaught has a chance to reward bounties which can be completed for reputation. Opening chests that require a key will reward a small amount of rep as well.
- Successfully completing a rune public event at the Court of Oryx.
- Finding one of the 50 calcified fragments rewards 10 rep (note that this will overlap with key chests in some parts)

Comment: You also get rep from the court of Oryx upon using and successfully completing a rune.

Comment: You also get rep for finding Calcified Fragments that are found on the dreadnaught.